# Null exception in faces renderkit

Tags: jsf, richfaces, glassfish-2.x

I get the following exception when I click a button on a JSF/RichFaces page.
This problem only seems to happen on one server. Any ideas?

```
StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getCurrentSelectedValues(MenuRenderer.java:633)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOption(MenuRenderer.java:524)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOptions(MenuRenderer.java:757)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:811)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:335)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:836)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:279)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:242)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:812)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:271)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:242)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:812)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:886)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:137)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:812)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:886)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:892)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:245)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:176)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:144)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:245)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:333)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:313)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:287)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:94)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1096)
        at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:288)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:647)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:579)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:831)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.executeProcessorTask(DefaultReadTask.java:341)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:263)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultReadTask.doTask(DefaultReadTask.java:214)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
```

here's the page causing the problem:

```
    <h:form id="clientCreatorForm" >
        <h1><h:outputText value="Linguist Creator"/></h1>
        <rich:messages styleClass="error_msg" showDetail="true" showSummary="true"/>
        <h:panelGrid id="op" columns="2">
            <rich:spacer height="20px" />
            <h:outputText value="" />
            <h:outputText value="Linguists:" />
            <rich:comboBox value="#{linguistCreator.linguistCompanyName}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{linguistCreator.companyItemsAvailable}" />
                <a4j:support action="#{linguistCreator.l1RequiredInputTest}"
                             ajaxSingle="true"
                             event="onselect"
                             reRender="footerPanel" />
            </rich:comboBox>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <rich:spacer height="20px" />
        <h:panelGrid id="footerPanel" columns="1" >
            <a4j:commandButton id="updatebutton" value="Add new Language(s) to selected linguist."
                               action="#{linguistCreator.retrieveLinguistObjects}"
                               disabled="#{linguistCreator.enterDisabledL1}"/>
            <a4j:commandButton id="addButton" value="Add new linguist" action="linguist2" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: What JSF RI 1.x version exactly is it using? Stack trace lines seem to match somewhere around 1.2_04/05, but that NPE does then not match. In any way, have you tried upgrading to latest, 1.2_15, just to exclude it being caused by one of the so many 1.2 bugs?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and downloaded the very latest version of JSF 1.2. Got the same results.

Comment: Okay, can you please at least tell the exact version used (Mojarra 1.2_16, right?) and edit your question to update the stack trace so that the line numbers match the exact version used? Then we can easily look in the source code for possible causes.

Comment: Yes, the version I am now using is 1.2_16. I have updated the stack trace as you requested.

Comment: Sorry, but the stack trace is identical to as you originally had and doesn't match version 1.2_16, so I can't help much.

Comment: Very confusing. I replaced the libraries in the project compilation. So I assume this is something inside the glassfish app server. How would I find out what version is in the app server and how would I update them to a latest version?

Comment: Just double-checked. I am definitely using the latest version of JSF that I downloaded from the JavaNet web page. I replaced both the jsf-api and jsf-impl jar files in my project's library classpath.